# 'This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node.'

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to create a xml document of following format

```
<TemplateID>xxxxx</TemplateID>
        <CaptionOptions>
          <CaptionField>
            <Field>xxx</Field>
            <Text>xxx</Text>
          </CaptionField>
          <CaptionField>
            <Field>xxxx</Field>
            <Text>""</Text>
          </CaptionField>
        </CaptionOptions>
```

Here is the code that I wrote

```
XmlDocument xml2 = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement e = xml2.CreateElement("TemplateID");
        e.InnerText = "xxxx";
        xml2.AppendChild(e);
        XmlElement root2 = xml2.CreateElement("CaptionOptions");
        xml2.AppendChild(root2);   //error here
        XmlElement child2a = xml2.CreateElement("CaptionField");
        root2.AppendChild(child2a);
        XmlElement child2aa = xml2.CreateElement("Field");
        child2a.InnerText = "xxxx";
        XmlElement child2ab = xml2.CreateElement("Text");
        child2a.InnerText = "xxxx";
        child2a.AppendChild(child2aa);
        child2a.AppendChild(child2ab);


        child2a.AppendChild(child2aa);
        child2a.AppendChild(child2ab);
```

My real code was different from the one I was trying to ask earlier....

Comment: `XmlElement` never have `Value`, it has `InnerText` instead : `child.InnerText = "Rooney";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create attributes and append them to the Player element. But your xml hierarchy doesn't look right.

As discussed, now edited.

```
       XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement template = doc.CreateElement("Template");
        XmlNode id = doc.CreateElement("TemplateID");
        id.InnerText = "123456";

        template.AppendChild(id);

        doc.AppendChild(template);

        XmlElement options = doc.CreateElement("CaptionOptions");
        XmlElement captionField = doc.CreateElement("CaptionField");
        XmlElement field1 = doc.CreateElement("Field");
        field1.InnerText = "Field1Text";
        XmlElement text1 = doc.CreateElement("Field");
        text1.InnerText = "Text1Text";

        captionField.AppendChild(field1);
        captionField.AppendChild(text1);

        options.AppendChild(captionField);

        template.AppendChild(options);

        string xml = doc.OuterXml;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: difference between XmlElement and XmlNode?

Comment: I want to add make a doc like <TemplateID>xxxx</TemplateID>
            <CaptionOptions>
              <CaptionField>
                <FieldID>xxxx</FieldID>
                <TextString>xxxx</TextString>
              </CaptionField>
              <CaptionField>
                <FieldID>xxxx</FieldID>
                <TextString>""</TextString>
              </CaptionField>
            </CaptionOptions>

Comment: An xmlelement is a sub class of an XMLNode. XMLNode is the base class.. i think. The answer I've posted creates you the doc. the doc has a save as method so you can save it to a file.

Comment: I am getting , " 'This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node.'
"

Comment: Well you've obviously not posted all of your code. If you run the code I've posted on its own it works. Can you not adapt what i've given you?

Comment: This was just an example. My Actual code is different.

Comment: OK.. but the XML structure you have posted as your desired output is not valid! Try it. Put it in an .xml file and drag it into a browser.

Comment: That is not the full structure. What do you mean? If you could just help out in the current problem I am facing. (There is one parent for template and caption options)

Comment: If you keep posting only "Parts" of what you are doing, its very hard to provide an answer. I've edited my answer to generate xml in a valid format similar to what you have now posted. You should be able to take it from there.

Comment: But it is not formatted like a xml doc is really like..How to do that?

Comment: Just browse the xml string generated from the doc or call the doc.Save method.. it will save the xml out. It is valid. as I said, the xml you posted in your question is not valid.

Comment: Also,  <CaptionField>
            <Field>xxxx</Field>
            <Text>""</Text>
          </CaptionField> is not repeated in your code

Comment: OK, though I was able to format into string though. using Formatting property of text writer

Comment: Just duplicate the CaptionField code block if you need more than one.

Comment: Doesn't work. I added options.AppendChild(captionField);

Comment: You need to duplicate the whole CaptionField code block with unique field names and append them to them template object as well!

Comment: Can you help out with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48618484/not-getting-xml-portion-in-formatted-form?noredirect=1#comment84236146_48618484

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
XmlElement child = xml.CreateElement("Players");
child.SetAttribute("Nationality", "England");
child.InnerText = "Rooney";
```